# MongoDB query faster lte than gte

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, mongodb-query

This issue is driving me crazy. I have a collection:

```
var ethTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    blockNumber: Number,
    blockHash: String,
    hash: String,
    transactionIndex: Number,
    from: String,
    to: String,
    value: String
});
ethTransactionSchema.index({ hash: 1 }, { unique: true });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1});

ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: 1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: 1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ transactionIndex: 1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: -1 });

ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, to: 1, blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1, blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ to: 1, blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 });
```

When I execute this query:

```
  find({"$and":[ {"$or": [ {"from":"0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad"},
                      {"to":"0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad"}
                    ]},
            {"blockNumber":{"$gte":1289597}}
          ]
  }).sort({ blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 })
```

It takes from 3 to 6 times more than the same query with lte:

```
  find({"$and":[ {"$or": [ {"from":"0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad"},
                      {"to":"0x120a270bbc009644e35f0bb6ab13f95b8199c4ad"}
                    ]},
            {"blockNumber":{"$lte":1289597}}
          ]
  }).sort({ blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1 })
```

You can see that I've tried lot of index combinations just to test if I can fix the issue using frute force, but I may be missing something. I'm about to drop MongoDB for this reason.
The fast query takes 56 ms and the slow 167 ms average.

Can someone figure out what's the problem or help me to find it?

Answer (score 4):

There are some issues with what you are trying to do:

1. **`$or` queries use indexes differently**

   For `$or` queries to be able to use an index, **all** terms of the `$or` query must have an index. Otherwise, the query will be a collection scan. This is described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes
2. **Too many indexes in the collection**

   Having too many indexes in a collection affects performance in more than one way, e.g., insert performance will suffer since you are turning one insert operation into many (i.e. one insert for the collection, and one additional insert for each indexes in your collection). Too many similar-looking indexes is also detrimental to the query planner, since it needs to choose one index out of many similar ones with minimal information on which index will be more performant.
3. **Check the `explain()` output in `mongo` shell**

   The `explain()` output in the `mongo` shell is the best tool to discover which index will be used by a query. Generally, you want to avoid any `COLLSCAN` stage (which means a collection scan) and `SORT_KEY_GENERATOR` stage (which means that MongoDB is using an in-memory sort that is limited to 32MB, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/). Please see [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) for more details.

You may want to check out these relevant pages regarding indexing and query performance:

- [Analyze Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/)
- [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)
- [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/)

Having said that, I did a quick check in `mongo` shell (MongoDB 3.2.8) using your examples. You could try adding these two indexes in your collection:

```
{blockNumber:1,transactionIndex:1,from:1}
{blockNumber:1,transactionIndex:1,to:1}
```

And **drop all the other indexes in the collection**. Those two indexes should be able to be used in your two examples queries.

Comment: It works worse with these indexes. I think that the problem is that some queries return a large number of documents and the sort takes time. I really don't get how explain can help me, it looks like assembly language. If the results are 67000 then the sort is slow. I used to use Cassandra where you can specify a default order of the table which is very useful when you need to retrieve always result with a certain order. It looks like Mongo lacks of this feature which would be what I need.